# No puedo acceder a una carpeta compartida desde PHP - WAMP

Tags: php, laravel, wamp

Buen dia.

Tengo instalado un servicio wamp en donde se encuentra una pagina web con laravel 5 y php 7.0.33.(Este proyecto estaba anteriormente instalado en otro servidor por medio de IIS.)

Tengo el siguiente problema.
Este sistema realiza una consulta a una base de datos para extraer una ruta (Ejm: \Ruta\archivo\texto.txt) y apartir de esta ruta extraer el archivo que se muestra ahi y descargarlo a la pagina.

El problema se presenta debido a que ahora que tengo instalado la pagina en wamp no me descarga el archivo.

Incluso algunos comandos como is_file, isdir, opendir siempre los retorna como false, como si no pudiera ingresar a esta ruta compartida.

La carpeta a la que intenta ingresar tiene los permisos para todos los usuarios

Aqui esta la funcion que se manda a llamar para descargar el pdf

```
public function pdfDownload($docnum)
{   
    $query = DB::select("select pdf from tabla where docnum = ".$docnum);
    $json = json_encode($query);
    $pathjson = json_decode($json);
    $pathToFile = $pathjson[0]->u_archivopdf;
    $headers = array(
          'Content-Type: application/pdf',
        );

    if(is_file($pathToFile)){
        return response()->download($pathToFile, $docnum.'.pdf', $headers);
    }else { 
        return back()->withErrors(['La Factura no ha sido timbrada', 'PDF']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Buen día, Este detalle lo resolví buscando en diferentes foros de Wamp.**

El problema se debe a como se inicia WampServer, ya que este inicia con un usuario default.

En la ruta encontré la solución a este problema.

Lo que debe realizar es:

- Ingresar a Servicios de windows (Inicio->Servicios)
- Buscas el servicio llamado WampApache, das clic derecho y seleccionas
  Propiedades
- Das clic a la pestaña Iniciar Sesión
- das check a esta "Esta cuenta"
- Colocar usuario y contraseña de la computadora/servidor donde tienes 
  montado el WAMP
- Reinicias el servicio.

Estuve días buscando y no encontraba la solución, espero les sirva esta respuesta para sus futuras dudas.

Answer (score -1):

Este problema se debe, probablemente, a los permisos que tenes asignados en el directorio de tu proyecto.

- Si tu SO es Linux: ubicate en el la carpeta de tu proyecto en la consola y utiliza el comando chmod -r 777 "NOMBREDELARCHIVO" (sin comillas).
- En windows desconozco como es el procedimiento.

Espero que te haya servido, saludos.